# Error: Error Deleting User with ID XXX graphrbac.UsersClient#Delete Authorization_RequestDenied - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, terraform

I have created my Service Principle and added all the neccessary permissions to read and write *Users* in my Azure Active Directory.

[image]

I run `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` on it and it works fine.

[image]

However, whenever I try to destroy(`terraform destroy`) the resource(*azuread_user*) to delete AD Users I get this error

[image]

What could I have done wrongly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Updated**: Added `.tf` file

```
provider "azuread" {
  version = "~> 0.11"
  subscription_id= var.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
  client_id       = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID
  client_secret   = var.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
  tenant_id       = var.ARM_TENANT_ID
}

resource "azuread_user" "main-user" {
  user_principal_name = var.email
  display_name        = var.name
  password            = var.password
}
```

Comment: Please share your terraform configuration in `.tf` file which deletes the AAD user.

Comment: Which version of terraform are you using ?

Comment: Also, make sure `NOTE: If you're authenticating using a Service Principal then it must have permissions to Directory.ReadWrite.All within the Windows Azure Active Directory API.`

Comment: @AllenWu - I've added my `.tf` file as an update, please.

Comment: @AmitBaranes - `Terraform v0.12.28`

Comment: ...and @AmitBaranes, I think I added the `Directory.ReadWrite.All` API permission too (both Delegated and Application types). Or?

Comment: Take a look at my answer, let me know if you find any issues later

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a test with your script and find that if we only give `Directory.ReadWrite.All` Delegated permission under Azure AD Graph, we can only create AAD user. When I tried to delete it with `terraform destroy`, I get the same error as yours.

So I tried another method:  assign a **Global Admin** role to the Service Principal in Azure portal. Then I can successfully delete the user.

See reference here: [Method 1: Directory Roles (recommended)](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/guides/service_principal_configuration.html#method-1-directory-roles-recommended-).

Comment: Right. This fixed it after assigning a `Global Administrator` role the SP... "T" for Thanks @Allen Wu... Saved me a lot of time. +1

Comment: Wow, that is like giving GODMODE to your SP. Sure you wanna go there ? If anyone get's their hands on those credentials.... Sorry, downvote because of serious security risk

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue related to the permissions the service principal has, I suggest creating a new one with full permissions for Azure AD. One way to check this theory is by trying to delete the user created by terraform using the az CLI.

First of all, use the existing service principal:

```sh
az login --service-principal --username APP_ID --password PASSWORD --tenant TENANT_ID
```

Later, try to delete the user by running:

```sh
az ad user delete --id %USER_ID%
```

In case the command failed, Create new service principal and assign admin permissions to Azure Active directory.

Also, from [terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/d/user.html) - `NOTE: If you're authenticating using a Service Principal then it must have permissions to Directory.ReadWrite.All within the Windows Azure Active Directory API`

Comment: Created a new SP but it still persisted :(

Comment: Just saw the approved answer, Looks like I way on the right way with the permissions issue. Glad the issue was fixed.

Comment: @JohnErbynn By the way, be careful with giving global administrator permission to terraform. In that case, you give Terraform permissions to any resource. in my opinion is to board.